If a non-state actor is recognized as a state organ, does that status persist?
In the ICJ's Iran v. United States case judgment, Khomeini's statement that the militants' actions were "done by our nation" effectively recognized them as state actions. Regarding the legal status of the protesters, the judgment states:
"The militants, authors of the invasion and jailers of the hostages, had now become agents of the Iranian State for whose acts the State itself was internationally responsible."(para.74)
Assume State A recognizes the actions of a non-state actor B as its own. If B violates a certain kind of international law a year later, can that action be attributed to State A? This question relates to the following specific questions:

If a specific act of a non-state actor is recognized by a state as its own, does the non-state actor immediately gain the status of a state organ? Is this a simultaneous legal status change?

Does the status of the non-state actor acquired in persist? For example, if the actor commits another act one year later, is that act also recognized as a state act?



It feels wrong for this to be true. When you hire someone to act as your agent, that shouldn't make you responsible for all future independent actions they take.

The question is seeking an answer at a high level of generality. I am not convinced that there is one at that level of generality. The law, even the quasi-legal construction of international law, is very fact and context driven and doesn't answer questions in the abstract.
